# Standard specification/description language for data charting?

Tags: ios, charts

**Motivation:** I'm part of a small team of developers working on an intranet web application. One major feature is the ability to view reports of data. These reports use JavaScript tables and Flash charts. However, we've recently started designing an iPad app that will allow users to view and configure these reports, and the charts have me stumped.

**Problem:** Basically, we use an implementation-specific format to store our chart configurations on the database. We have a JavaScript library for charting, but it would require us to manually recreate every chart on every report. Very time consuming. One of the requirements for the app is performance. It has to be faster than just using the existing web app from Safari, so UIWebView probably won't work.

It seems like the simplest solution is to use an iOS charting library like Core Plot. But then not only do we have to recreate every chart again, but we would have to maintain two versions of each chart. Maintenance nightmare.

The most desirable solution I can think of would be to store one standard, universal chart specification on the database. For each new charting implementation, we could then use existing configurations to generate implementation-specific configurations on the fly.

**Question:** Is there some sort of existing standard or charting description language we could use without having to develop our own? If not, are there other standards/languages that could be easily adapted for this purpose?

**Secondary question:** Is there another, better way of being able to display charts in a web client and an iOS app without just running the web page through UIWebView, and without having to maintain multiple configurations?

EDIT: I found the Microsoft Report Definition Language (RDL) Specification and it's basically the concept I'm looking for. I'll probably work with my team on adapting parts of it for our current needs.